# Mounting Ultrasonic Sensor on Metal Container to Measure Liquid Level

Tags: sensor, ultrasound

Is it possible to mount an ultrasonic sensor on the outer metal surface of tank/container to measure the level of the inside liquid ? the gap between the sensor and the metal surface would be 0 mm to 0.5 mm max.

Will the metal surface interfere the waves of sound or it will penetrate the metal due to the tiny gap ?  (Picture showing the idea)

[image]

Comment: Surely you will need a hole... but see https://www.amazon.com/Smart-Oil-Gauge-Heating-Compatible/dp/B01M2VATHS

Comment: Thanks for the suggested sensor on this link, I'm not sure about making any holes in the body of the tank, by the way it's the tank of my car & I'm developing a way to accurately measure the fuel level by average of four sensors on the corners (to eliminate the moving liquid effect) .. I think for insurance & after-sales services issues I cannot drill holes in the tank.

Comment: well good luck - why do you think the float type gauge is still used? You may as well consider mounting the tank on a set of bathroom scales and subtracting readings due to vehicle motion... And, only for points of measurement : what about the irregularities in the liquid surface...

Comment: Imagine an ulterasound imaging camera checking a baby growing in the womb. Would it work through a metal plate?

Comment: Andy aka - Yeah, I totally agree that metal is a strong reflective surface, but after I watched this video I asked this question - Please check it out if you don't mind https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwBqnNbKsPo

Comment: Solar Mike - Float gauge doesn't provide an accurate reading, it's varying between big range of Ohms.. additionally I want to combine that idea with odometer & the speed sensor to get mileage/fuel range & a record of fuel consumption, I think using four sensors on corners or additional one on the middle of the tank with overcome the irregularities by averaging the reads for a fine accuracy, no need here for high accuracy but float gauge cannot provide this level of accuracy.

Comment: So your question is defunct as the video answers it... and you knew that...

Comment: Solar Mike - I was believing that my idea is not applicable till I watched the video while I was adding comments here (I didn't know it before), but are those a specific type of sensors or the regular sensors like HC-SR04 can do the task ? & how the waves not being stopped by the metal !

Comment: that's an interesting video, did you notice that the sensor is glued to the underside of the tank?

Comment: Yeah, & that's a new question, why not on the top & how it detects the level this way ?

Comment: sound waves travel better though solids and liquids than they do through gasses,  so it's easier to measure from underneath. but you need s contsct transducer, not one designed for use in air.

Comment: Even a sensor in each corner won't help to to get accurate measurements unless you know the internal geometry of your tank. There's no guarantee it's a simple object as it may have some parts narrower/shallower than others.

Answer (score 2):

## Can you do this?:

Yes.  We do it all the time.  Having a thin metal tank wall can actually be preferable over a thick wall.  In our case, the wall thickness can be 10-20mm as we routinely operate from ambient to 20,000 psi (140 MPa) and 120 C.

It is easier to shoot from the bottom up through the liquid, to the liquid's surface, as the liquid more closely matches the acoustic impedance of the transducer and tank wall (better than air anyway).

## Does it work well?

Yes. But it's hard.  You will need:

- a quality source (ours is proprietary)
- quality transducer (ours is proprietary)
- a quality pulse/echo interface (yes)
- and quality tuned receiver (you betcha, our own).
- a high speed, synchronized, A2D converter (the easy part).

## If you manage to design/acquire the above bits, then the accuracy reduced down to 3 things:

- The calibration of the speed of acoustics in the liquid (which is temperature and pressure dependent).  This is also done automatically in our systems - every other shot is a speed calibration shot.
- The frequency of the transducer.  Higher frequencies will typically result in higher resolution.  Of course there are limits (we operate higher than 1 MHz).
- Your arrival detection algorithm.  There are all sorts. From simple time-of-flight on a scope (the most susceptible to error/interference), to embedding the maths in the silicon.  That's up to you and your resources.

## Does this apply well to a fuel tank?

I have some concerns here.  If you're not careful, these type of signals and energy levels can results in arcs.  Don't explode yourself.

The large surface area of the tank will reduce accuracy.  This is because a small vertical distance results in a relatively large volume change.  And add in a moving platform, sloshing, potholes, and I think that you're in for a noisy measurement.  **There are ways to mitigate these things.**  I'll let you think about that for a bit.

Good luck.

-Chris